# How can I make a cascade deletion in a one_to_many relationship in Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a model in rails with one_to_many relationship. When I delete the father, I'd like to delete all childrens. How should I do it? I want to delete all orders and its items when I delete a user

My models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :foreign_key => "id_user"
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items, :foreign_key => "id_pedido"
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "id_usuer"
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, :foreign_key => "id_pedido"
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jdl's answer is correct - you need to add `:dependent => :destroy` to both relationships - i.e. in your `User` class, add it to `has_many :orders`, and in your `Order` class, add it to `has_many :order_items`.

You might also want to change the MySQL behaviour wrt foreign keys, perhaps setting them to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: You are both right @jdl and @cite. What I was doing wrong was that I was calling the delete method besides the destroy method. Now everything works fine

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the `:dependent => :destroy` option on `has_many`.

[has_many docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833)

Comment: I tried it, but I get this: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`detam2`.`order_items`, CONSTRAINT `FKE3418DF1BA998374` FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE (`id` IN (31)) 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`detam2`.`order_items`, CONSTRAINT `FKE3418DF1BA998374` FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `pedidos` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE (`id` IN (31))

Comment: You are both right @jdl and @cite. What I was doing wrong was that I was calling the delete method besides the destroy method. Now everything works fine